# TYPO3 9.5: Contact form spam prevention without setting Cookies

Tags: typo3, contact-form, typo3-9.x

Is there any TYPO3 extension for version 9, which can be used for spam protection in TYPO3's contact form, **but does not set any Cookies**? I used reCAPTCHA earlier, but it's setting so many Cookies from Google. My goal is to have a "Cookie-free" website. Does such an extension exist or is there any other alternative how to protect my contact form from spambots?

Just in case: I am able to use Google Search, but before installing and trying any available extension out, I am rather asking, if maybe someone already knows a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a concrete issue with spam?

The core's EXT:form uses a honeypot field which is generated randomly, appears at different places and serves us well.

So i would not recommend to search for a solution that is not really needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot give an answer to this question so far, because I just disabled the reCATPCHA extension. Also I didn't know that the core's form uses a honeypot field. I just know from earlier Joomla Websites, that I received many many spam messages until I installed a spam-protection. Maybe I will wait some time and see what happens.

Comment: i'd recommend that too! just wait a while and check for eventual spam - i there's non then you should be find.
If you're still thinking about the EXT:recaptcha you should keep stuff like GDPR in mind as there might be external resources in usage or check for alternatives too
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/easycaptcha/

Comment: Another approach could be to activate a confirmation page. So after submitting the form, the visitor is redirected to a page which displays the form data and asks if everything is fine. To submit the form, another click is necessary. Backdraw of this solution: you might loose form data because the visitor left the page too fast because he didn't expect this behavior. But it can be circumvented with proper labels and good wording.